# Filling the comparison table with values on Angular 8

Tags: html, node.js, angular, typescript

I need to fill out the table with the values ​​of the characteristics, but I can’t understand how to enter certain values ​​in the corresponding columns

My model data has:

```
productInformations:
    {productId: 113698, name: "Asus PRIME H270-PRO Soc-1151"},
    {productId: 113715, name: "MSI H110M PRO-VD Soc-1151"}

comparisonProducts:
    sectionName: "Memory"
    comparisonSpecifications:
        specificationName: "Memory slots DDR4"
        details:
            {productId: 113698, value: "4"}
            {productId: 113715, value: "2"}

        specificationName: "Type of memory supported"
        details:
            {productId: 113698, value: "DIMM"}
            {productId: 113715, value: "DIMM"}

//... order data//
```

I create a table using ngFor loop

```
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th *ngFor="let product of comparisonResult.productInformations">{{product.name}}</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let comparison of comparisonResult.comparisonProducts">
            <td><b>{{comparison.sectionName}}</b>
              <ul *ngFor="let comparisonSpec of comparison.comparisonSpecifications">
                <li>
                  {{comparisonSpec.specificationName}}
                </li>
              </ul>
            </td>
            <td *ngFor="let item of comparison.details">
              {{item.value}} //as I understand it, here I need to bind the value to a specific productId
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

[Example](https://angular-jw4hbn.stackblitz.io)